# Polymorphism and creation of Object using String

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I declared an Interface like the following

```
public interface One {
    void setNo(int no);
}
```

Then I have a class to implement the interface

```
public class Two implements One{
    private int no;

    @Override
    public void setNo(int no){
        this.no = no;
    }
}
```

I will have a lot of classes to implement the interface and then I want to create the corresponding Object according to user input.

Let's say we have the classes Three, Four, Five described as the Two class.

The user picks to create the class Three. So I try to do something like the following

```
One base;

Class c = Class.forName("Three");
base = (One) c.newInstance();

base.setNo(5);
```

the call to base.setNo() fails. Am I doing this right?

Error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Three
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: What's the error? and is your code above even compiling?

Comment: Try using the fully qualified class name

Comment: In addition, if the code of Three is similar to Two, `setNo` is package private, which means you can't access it from a class that's not in the same package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include package name
so if your class Three in package com.test then you should write this way

```
Class c = Class.forName("com.test.Three");
    base = (One) c.newInstance();

    base.setNo(5);
```

Comment: well it is obvious, because forName method requires fully qualified class name, for example there are two classes/files with same name "List" (java.awt and java.utils) how do you think forName method will distinguish them without package name?

Answer (score 1):

It should give compilation error:

**Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from One**

Try to make method as public.

```
public class Two implements One{
    private int no;

    @Override
    public void setNo(int no){
        this.no = no;
    }
}
```

I don't know where are you created Three class, but I can help with your Two class.

```
public class Two implements One {
     private int no;

        @Override
        public void setNo(int no){
            this.no = no;
            System.out.println("No-->");
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            One base;

            Class c;
            try {
                c = Class.forName("com.test.stackoverflow.Two");
                base = (One) c.newInstance();
                base.setNo(5);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}
```